# files with extra suffix in batch

Tags: batch-file, batch-rename

I'm trying to list all the files which have extra suffix after the extension
E.g: .txt.1 or .txt.2 etc..

I'm using *txt.* but it's giving all the file names instead of only the files with extra suffix

```
for %%A in (*txt.*) do (call :renum "%%A")
```

after this I'm writing my program to rename the files accordingly.
Can someone please check and help.

Comment: The pattern should read `*.txt.*` (note the added dot)...

Comment: @aschipfl: have you tried what happens when you do that?

Comment: tried that already, but it didn't work

Comment: @zb226, no I haven't, but it's obvious that `*txt.*` matches something like `file.txtxtxt.1` but `*.txt.*` doesn't; besides that, there is no more difference, both will match `file.txt.1.2` (unintentionally)...

Comment: If you know precise character limitations, then you could perhaps use ? instead of *, which may help a little. However, you may still need to run an additional if check inside your for loop, like zb226' answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One solution would be to filter by extension inside the loop:

```
FOR %%A IN (*txt.*) DO (
    IF NOT "%%~xA"==".txt" CALL :renum "%%A"
)
```

This works by using the "enhanced substitution of `FOR` variable references", in this case `%%~xA`. You can get an overview of all the available substitutions by executing `FOR /?`.

**Update:**

- This solution does not work case-insensitively, because that was neither explicitly demanded or prohibited. Use `IF /I` instead of plain `IF` if case-insensivity is desired.
- As [dbenham](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1012053/dbenham) notes, there are edge cases:

  - `name.txt.txt` **will not** be processed. If that's OK is not clearly stated, but rather likely.
  - `name_txt.ext` **will** be processed, which is due to the given wildcard `*txt.*` and can be avoided by using `*.txt.*` instead. My rationale to not change it in the first place was that only the OP knows his actual set of files, and I assumed he had a reason for choosing it (a situation common in these types of questions).

Comment: This will not work if a file is named "name.txt.txt"

Comment: This will also improperly process a name like "name_txt.ext"

Comment: @dbenham: You're right - I commented on these issues.

Answer (score 1):

You could use two nested `for` loops like this:

```dos
rem // Corrected file pattern (added a `.`):
for %%A in ("*.txt.*") do (
    rem // Check (last) file extension:
    if /I not "%%~xA"==".txt" (
        rem // Remove (last) file extension:
        for %%B in ("%%~nA") do (
            rem // Check next-to-last file ext.:
            if /I "%%~xB"==".txt" (
                call :renum "%%~A"
            )
        )
    )
)
```

According to the help of `for` (type `for /?` in a command prompt window), the `~x` modifier of the `for` variable retrieves the file extension (which is the last dot `.` and everything after). The `~n` modifier retrieves all but the file extension, hence the file (base) name. The code above uses two nested `for` loops to get the last and the next-to-last file extensions and checking them against `.txt` (in a case-insensitive manner).

Note that the `call` command line is not executed for files ending in `.txt.txt`.

Comment: +1, But I don't understand why you included your first IF statement that filters out names like "name.txt.txt". I suppose that might be desired in some circumstances, but I would probably want to rename names like that.

Comment: @dbenham, because of the OP's example where the extra suffix is numeric like `.1`, `.2`,... I assumed if the last extension is `.txt`, it is already fine...

Answer (score 1):

I would use FINDSTR with DIR /B and FOR /F

The following will process names with any number of extra extensions like `name.txt.ext` and `name.txt.ext.ext`, etc. This includes a name like `name.txt.txt`

```
for /f "delims= eol=:" %%F in (
  'dir /b /a-d *.txt.*^|findstr /i "\.txt\."'
) do call :renum "%%F"
```

This variation will only process names with a single extra extension like `name.txt.ext` (including `name.txt.txt`)

```
for /f "delims= eol=:" %%F in (
  'dir /b /a-d *.txt.*^|findstr /i "\.txt\.[^.]*$"'
) do call :renum "%%F"
```

You might also check into my [JREN.BAT regular expression file renaming utility](http://www.dostips.com/forum/viewtopic.php?t=6081). It can probably filter and rename all your files in one step, without any need for a custom batch script.

For example, the following will only rename files looking like "name.txt.ext", and transform them into "name_ext.txt"

```
jren "(\.txt)\.([^.]+)$" "_$2$1" /i
```

Comment: What if the file name has txt in it?

Comment: @Bharath - The leading dot literal in the search string prevents matching txt within the base name. Technically speaking, `.txt` would be considered part of the base name if it is not at the end, but we are assuming that is the intended extension.

Comment: @Bharath - If you want to include a name like `XXXXtxt.ext`, without the leading dot. then simply use `'dir /b /a-d *txt.*^|findstr /i "txt\."'`